# Пропуск катсцены(сделанной с помощью Timeline)

Tags: c#, unity3d, timeline

Сразу после загрузки сцены начинает проигрываться катсцена,сделанная с помощью Timeline. Потом геймплей, если игрок умирает сцена просто загружается заново и катсцена,разумеется,тоже проигрывается ещё раз.
Что сделать, что бы была возможность пропустить катсцену?

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: Я ещё не делал попыток ибо не нашел ничего по теме